# Giving points in the same delimited text layer multiple colours-while using point displacement

Tags: qgis, point, symbology, style, color

I want to give multiple colours to points within the same delimited text layer, while using point displacement, looking for advice on how best to do this.

The data are showing occurrences of a variety of species in an area. I'm displaying my points using point displacement, as there are some over-lapping co-ordinates. I would like to show a different colour for each species while still using point displacement.

I've tried splitting the data and creating a separate layer for each species, giving each species layer its own colour in that way. However, when I do this I've only been able to assign point displacement symbology to each layer individually and not to all the data at once-so I end up with overlapping points again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point displacement style allows having the rendered of your choice. For this task, select `categorized` then click the `renderer settings` below

[image]

You can then pick the category, select a color ramp and classify the data.

When done, click the `back` arrow at the top

[image]